# How to use the .multi() method? (substrate-front-end-template)

Tags: pallet, javascript, query, substrate-front-end, rmrk

I finished the [substrate kitty tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/kitties/pt2/) (backend and frontend). Now I would like to build a simple frontend for the [RMRK pallet](https://github.com/rmrk-team/rmrk-substrate). Now I stuck on the .multi(...) method. Where can I find a documentation about this .multi-method?

```
      unsub = await api.query.rmrkCore.collections.multi(collectionIds, collections => {
          const collectionsMap = collections.map(collection => parseCollection(collection.unwrap()));
          setCollections(collectionsMap);
      });
```

The collection.unwrap() returns an error because it is [null,null]

--> However, with the following code I get a nice map<id,collections>

```
const entries = await api.query.rmrkCore.collections.entries();
const ids = entries.map(entry => entry[0]);
setCollectionIds(ids);
```

My goal is to parse the collections and store them (setCollections(collectionsMap))

I am grateful about any help :)

Comment: Not sure if this is useful but have you taken a look at: https://github.com/rmrk-team/rmrk-tools#collection

Comment: Also, where can do you see this `multi()` method? I cannot find it.

Comment: I found the solution :) In the RMRK pallet you don't have to query a collection by it's ID - api.query.rmrkCore.collections.entries() returns already ALL collections. Not sure if this will be performant in the future but for now I get all collection-data for all collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an [example](https://github.com/polkadot-js/docs/blob/2a29d083e12ec456a2a226a79181fa4fe7c59538/docs/api/examples/promise/read-storage-at.md) in the polkadot-js-docs. In short: it is a multi-query to retrieve several objects. I guess in the kitty-tutorial first the ids of the single objects are retrieved and second for each id the body is queried in a multi-query.

here the example from the docs:

```
// Import the API
const { ApiPromise } = require('@polkadot/api');

// Our address for Alice on the dev chain
const ALICE = '5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY';
const BOB = '5FHneW46xGXgs5mUiveU4sbTyGBzmstUspZC92UhjJM694ty';

async function main () {
  // Create our API with a default connection to the local node
  const api = await ApiPromise.create();

  // Retrieve the last block header, extracting the hash and parentHash
  const { hash, parentHash } = await api.rpc.chain.getHeader();

  console.log(`last header hash ${hash.toHex()}`);

  // Retrieve the balance at the preceding block for Alice. For at queries
  // the format is always `.at(<blockhash>, ...params)`
  const balance = await api.query.system.account.at(parentHash, ALICE);

  console.log(`Alice's balance at ${parentHash.toHex()} was ${balance.data.free}`);

  // Now perform a multi query, returning multiple balances at once
  const balances = await api.query.system.account.multi([ALICE, BOB]);

  console.log(`Current balances for Alice and Bob are ${balances[0].data.free} and ${balances[1].data.free}`);
}
```